# Is it possible to design an antenna with constant antenna aperture (that doesn't vary with frequency)?

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, radio

As per the title, I'm interested to know if it's possible, either theoretically or practically, to have an antenna design which has a constant effective aperture (antenna aperture - these are the same thing right?) over some (non-infinitesimal) frequency range. If so, what are the conditions required?

For context, I have a hunch that for any antenna if the frequency is below a certain cutoff point it will have a constant effective aperture with frequency, but I've been unable to find anything to prove this hunch.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think so.

Comment: The aperture size is fixed by the physical size of the antenna, at least for antenna arrays.

Comment: @SteveSh I'm referring to the effective aperture, which typically varies with wavelength. It's not a fixed quantity

Comment: @Christian - We build antenna arrays using notch or patch elements.  For those antennas the effective aperture (the capture area) is the same as the physical aperture.

Comment: Acoustic horns provide constant directivity by using shapes that open up fast enough to let frequencies leave the boundary before they get too focused.  I would imagine that an antenna where you don't have as localized an emitter as with a horn driver but can better distribute active elements and guides would be able to use similar techniques.  Acoustical horns of good quality tend to cover about a decade of frequency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hunch that there is a "cutoff point" in the relationship between frequency and aperture is correct, but you have the consequences reversed.

For antennas that are large compared to the wavelength -- such as a horn, dish, or large array -- the effective aperture is roughly the physical size of the antenna, and can be fairly constant over a wide range of wavelength (or frequencies).

For antennas that are on the order of a wavelength or smaller -- which you could consider as being below your "cutoff point" in frequency -- it's practically very difficult to design an antenna with a constant effective aperture over a wide range of frequencies. As the antenna becomes small with regard to wavelength, the radiation resistance drops and the reactive impedance rises, leading to losses that reduce the effective aperture.

Comment: But you can design antenna (elements) that have very little insertion loss (less than 0.5 dB) over a 10:1 or 20:1 frequency range.

Comment: I think my hunch came from seeing a graph of the correction factor for a magnetic loop antenna, which had a negative gradient on a log-log graph up to a certain frequency, at which point the graph became flat. Baring in mind the relationship between effect aperture and wavelength, it suggested to me that the antenna may have a constant effective aperture in the region of negative gradient (though this reasoning doesn't consider varying values of gain).

Comment: Example graph I was referring to in my above comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michal-Ulvr/publication/262308078/figure/fig2/AS:613855457726474@1523365954475/Magnetic-Antenna-Factor-for-HZ-10-loop.png